# Como puedo insertar valores en ArrayList despues ha haber recorrido un resulset

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo problemas para insertar los totales a un ArrayList me esta insertando valores null, los registros que se recuperan dentro del bloque while se insertan correctamente, sin embargo, ya no se insertan correctamente los valores despues del bloque while, aun y cuando las sumas tienen valores diferentes a null

esta es la función

```
fun recuperarDetalleRecibos(idr:Int):ArrayList<HashMap<String,Any>>{
val arrayList=ArrayList<HashMap<String,Any>>()
val sql="select concepto,importe,interesreal from recibosdetalle where idrecibo=$idr"
var sumadescuento:Double=0.00
var sumaimporte:Double=0.00
var sumainteresreal:Double=0.00
var concepto:String
var importe:Double
var interesreal:Double
try{
    var rs = claseSQL().consulta(sql)
    if (rs != null) {
        while (rs.next()){
            concepto=rs.getString(1)
            importe=rs.getDouble(2)
            interesreal=rs.getDouble(3)

            if(importe<0){
                sumadescuento-=importe
            }else{
                sumaimporte+=importe
            }
            sumainteresreal+=interesreal
```

`
// Estos valores los inserta bien

```
            val map=HashMap<String,Any>()
            map.put("concepto",concepto)
            map.put("importe",importe)
            arrayList.add(map)
        }
```

//AQUI DESPUES DEL BLOQUE WHILE ES DONDE EN LUGAR DE INSERTAR LAS SUMAS ME INSERTA UN VALOR NULL

```
        val map=HashMap<String,Any>()
        map.put("sumadescuento",sumadescuento)
        map.put("sumaimporte",sumaimporte)
        map.put("sumainteresreal",sumainteresreal)
        arrayList.add(map)


    }else{
        Log.e("Error", "Error al recuperar los datos del consulta: " + sql)
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("Error al recuperar el detalle de los recibos",e.printStackTrace().toString())
}
return arrayList
```

}